# CakePHP users showing another users data in their dashboard

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP Project in which there is login in front end by auth plugin. Different Users have their own login details. It seems okay when I login with any details, but when an user login on college lab computer he/she see their profile but when another users login with their own login details he/she show dashboard of another user which have loged in previously.

I think its store session value at same place for all systems in college lab. Is this make sense?

Please let me know where its wrong??

Thanks

Comment: The sessions are saved on the webserver so that it doesn't matter, if the users are using the college lab computer. But maybe there is a problem with a proxy server that caches some profile pages.

Comment: Thanks for clear session storage issue... so how to stop proxy server for cache...so each user can see their own profile/dashboard?
is it possible that I can solve this issue by any cakephp settings/config....because its not possible to work/change on college proxy server.

Comment: You can disable caching by sending some additional header information. See section "Example #2 Caching directives" in http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php: `<?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");?>`

Comment: Thanks for solution... If I put this code in top of layout file then it will work??? I can not check it right now because I am not in college....so I can check in my next meeting with client in college.

Comment: If you are using CakePHP it should be better to call `$this->response->disableCache()` in you AppControllers `beforeRender()`. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse::disableCache

Comment: Thank you so much....I'll try this.

Comment: Before doing anything you should confirm/identify the actual cause for your problem (i.e. _is_ it browser caching?).

Comment: The title is very funny. What is your login script?

Comment: I loged in using Auth.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with help of "Mario" answer. Actually there was issue of cache in college lab systems. Because when I open an page its show profile of another user which have open his profile previously on his system. and when I refresh my page its show me my profile. Means its changing session value with the user who have visit page recently.

So I add following code in app controller in before filter function

`$this->response->disableCache();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");`

and changed "Security.level" to medium from low.

`Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');`

Thanks Mario...